# I found all the daedric artifacts; but I am not getting the award

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I found all the daedric artifacts; but I am not getting the award. Looked up the quests and everything is completed. Nothing left undone. So how do I get the award ?

Comment: How many artifacts do you have?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Oblivion_Walker), there are 15 artifacts required to obtain this trophy. Technically there is 17 in total, but 4 are mutually exclusive (supposedly) - there are two quests that reward one item *or* another. These are the Ring of Hircine/Saviour's Hide, and the Azura's Star/The Black Star. The Skeleton Key is not *meant* to contribute to this achievement, since it is intended to be returned at the end of the questline.

However, this bug has occurred before, and some have found a solution to it.

If in the "Ill Met by Moonlight" quest, you chose to help Sinding, and obtain the Ring of Hircine, return to the Bloated Man's Grotto, and kill Sinding. This should make Hircine appear, and award the Saviour's Hide. If you wish to maintain a game with Sinding alive, save beforehand - you will maintain the trophy, but lose the Hide.

Comment: Note that some quest have endings that don't allow you to obtain the artifact. If done so, the achievement can't be earned. Also note that the Black Star gives the achievement, and both the Hide and Ring can be obtained in one playthrough.